# [Azure]: Error: Windows Azure is currently performing an operation on this hosted service that requires exclusive access

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

We are creating 2 cloud services in parallel with one deployment(VM Role) in each cloud service. For both requests (Sometimes only on 1) we are getting the following 409 Conflict error as a response to create hosted service POST request:

> 409 ConflictError : Windows Azure is currently performing an operation
>   on this hosted service that requires exclusive access.

On getting the exception we have a cleanup call and in retry we are trying to create again. On each retry we are using a new cloud service name.

The error occurs few times, every time we invoke the creation of 2 cloud services with VM in parallel. And on 2-15 retries, its getting created successfully. However when we invoke 1 cloud service creation with VM, we are not seeing this error.
Not sure why this error is thrown during simultaneous creations. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to catch the error and retry now, it's a limitation of Windows Azure. Azure requires most requests to be serialized.

Something like this, you can change `Stop-AzureVM` to your command require exclusive access.

```
$error.Clear();

Stop-AzureVM -Name $VMName -ServiceName $CloudServiceName -Force

$retryCount=0;

while($error[0].Exception.Message.Contains("ConflictError") -and $retryCount -le 10)
{
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 180
    Stop-AzureVM -Name $VMName -ServiceName $CloudServiceName -Force
    $retryCount = $retryCount + 1;        
}
```

Comment: Can you please add more details to your answer?

Comment: I was reviewing your post and added the comment to increase the quality of your answer

Comment: @Srikanth, Good, please give me your comments.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I looks better now. I am not well versed in azure to say if your answer is good or not. The up votes and down votes decide how good the answer is. If it solves OP`s problem, OP will accept the answer.